# bind the value from the list to a variable to make an api query

Tags: javascript, html, api

There is a button with a random joke which shows a joke depending on the category. The list of categories is obtained by API request `https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories`

The joke output is obtained at `https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category={category}`

Question: how to get a specific name `{category}` when clicking on a category based on the code below (when clicking on a category, the page should not be updated)?

```
function foo() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories', false);

    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ` ` + xhr.statusText);
    }

    let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(dataObject);
    let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    dataObject.forEach(item => {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "<a href='" + item + "'>" + item + "</a>";
        div.classList.add("div-added");
        div.id = 'items';
        menu.append(div);
    });
    let currentCategory;
    let items = document.querySelectorAll("#items");
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(items[i]);
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please explain in more detail what is the problem you are facing? What do you expect the code do and what does it do instead?

Comment: @Esko  
at this stage, my code blocks reloading the page when clicking on the category name, the problem is how to get the name of this category when clicking

Comment: Well it blocks the page because you use a synchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

function foo() {

```
let dataObject = getRemoteData('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories');
console.log(dataObject);

let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
dataObject.forEach(item => {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=getJoke('" + item + "')>" + item + "</a>";
    div.classList.add("div-added");
    div.id = 'items';
    menu.append(div);
});
```

}

function getJoke(token) {

```
let jokeData = getRemoteData("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=" + token);

// Write code to use that joke data     
console.log(jokeData);
```

}

function getRemoteData(url) {

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.send();

if (xhr.status !== 200) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ` ` + xhr.statusText);
}

return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

}

Comment: Check this code this should work. The only mistake was that u was using <a> with href instead u should use "onclick" event to pass the category name to a function which will make another request to other url which will give u the joke data

Comment: This same code snippet u can write more effectively with JS promises. Which are part of ES6. I will recommend to use promises for async operations like network requests. It helps to chain the code of async data in very efficient way. For more details about promises follow the link : http://javascript.info/promise-basics